# How can I pass a ctx (Context) to CliRunner?

Tags: python, python-click

`CliRunner` lists no parameter to provide a context in its [documentation](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#click.testing.CliRunner.invoke).

The following should qualify as a minimum working example.
The real problem is a bit different.
It could be solved by moving the click decorated function into its own function for test coverage. Then the click function would be rendered almost useless.

```py
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner

class Config():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 651

@click.command()
@click.pass_context
def print_numberinfo(ctx):
    if not hasattr(ctx.obj, 'value'):
        ctx.obj = Config()
    click.echo(ctx.obj.value)

def test_print_numberinfo():
    ctx = click.Context(print_numberinfo, obj = Config())
    ctx.obj.value = 777
    runner = CliRunner()
    # how do I pass ctx to runner.invoke?
    result = runner.invoke(print_numberinfo)
    assert result.output == str(ctx.obj.value) + '\n'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would directly pass your `Config` instance as keyword argument `obj` to `runner.invoke`:

```
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner

class Config():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 651

@click.command()
@click.pass_obj
def print_numberinfo(obj):
    if not hasattr(obj, 'value'):
        obj = Config()
    click.echo(obj.value)

def test_print_numberinfo():
    obj = Config()
    obj.value = 777
    runner = CliRunner()
    # how do I pass ctx to runner.invoke?
    result = runner.invoke(print_numberinfo, obj=obj)
    assert result.output == str(obj.value) + '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I wanted to pass a db session from the test side to my command method.

Here's my related code snippets and workaround using `@click.pass_context`:

### command method

```py
import asyncclick as click
import inspect
from getpass import getpass
from . import crud, schemas, database

class Provide:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def inject_db(f):
    sig = inspect.signature(f)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for param in sig.parameters.values():
            if isinstance(param.default, Provide):
                async for db in param.default.value():
                    kwargs[param.name] = db
                    await f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@click.group()
@click.pass_context
async def cli(ctx):
    pass

@cli.command(name="create_superuser")
@click.pass_context
@inject_db
async def create_superuser(ctx, db: database.AsyncSession = Provide(database.get_db)):
    if ctx.obj is not None:
        """ctx comes from test"""
        db = ctx.obj

    username = click.prompt("Username", type=str)
    email = click.prompt("Email (optional)", type=str, default="")
    password = getpass("Password: ")
    confirm_password = getpass("Confirm Password: ")

    if password != confirm_password:
        click.echo("Passwords do not match")
        return

    user = schemas.UserAdminCreate(
        username=username,
        email=None if not email else email,
        password=password,
        role="admin",
    )
    await crud.create_user(db=db, user=user)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()

cli.add_command(create_superuser)
```

### test part

```py
@pytest.mark.asyncio
@patch("ai3d.commands.click.prompt", side_effect=["testuser", "testemail@asa.com"])
@patch("ai3d.commands.getpass", side_effect=["testpassword", "testpassword"])
async def test_create_superuser(
    mock_getpass, mock_prompt, mock_get_hashed_password, db: AsyncSession
):
    with mock_get_hashed_password:
        runner = CliRunner()
        result = await runner.invoke(commands.create_superuser, obj=db)

        assert result.exit_code == 0
        mock_prompt.assert_any_call("Username", type=str)
        mock_prompt.assert_any_call("Email (optional)", type=str, default="")
        mock_getpass.assert_any_call("Password: ")
        mock_getpass.assert_any_call("Confirm Password: ")

        user = await crud.get_user(db=db, username="testuser")
        assert user.username == "testuser"
        assert user.email == "testemail@asa.com"
        assert user.password == "hashedtestpassword"
        assert user.role == "admin"
```

---

[NOTE]:

- I should add that in my case I'm using the `asynclick` package which is a fork of `click` providing async stuff, that's why I used `async-awiat` within the code.
- The key part of this answer is passing the object through the `obj=` parameter in `CliRunner().invoke()` method and using `@click.pass_context` decorator and `ctx` parameter for catching it.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who just want to make `context.obj` works like call from command-line:

```
CliRunner().invoke(commands.cli, ['sayhello'], catch_exceptions=False)
```

The first argument should be the the root group of click, then you can pass the command you want to call to the second argument(that is `sayhello`).

---

How `commands.py` like:

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import click


@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    ctx.obj = {
        'foo': 'bar'
    }


@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def sayehello(ctx):
    click.echo('hello!' + ctx.obj)
```

---

Appreciate to [geowurster](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/267#issuecomment-271777792) providing the solution.