# Typer: Pass context in test

Tags: python, click, command-line-interface, typer

I have a function that receives a callback argument from the context in the following way:

```py
@app.command()
def my_func(
    ctx: typer.Context,
):

    settings = ctx.obj.settings
```

Now I want to write a unit test for this function, but I'm unsure of how to pass the context to the `CliRunner` for the text:

```py
from typer.testing import CliRunner
runner = CliRunner()

def test_my_func():
    res = runner.invoke(app, ["my-func"])
    assert res.exit_code == 0
```

And I get the error

```bash
<Result AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'settings'")>
```

I tried to mock with `@patch("my_proj.my_module.typer.Context"` this doesn't seem to work. So, what is the right way to mock or pass the context to the runner during testing?

The following thread answers a similar question w.r.t. to click: [How can I pass a ctx (Context) to CliRunner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443368/how-can-i-pass-a-ctx-context-to-clirunner)

But since the callbacks won't work in typer the same solution wouldn't work.

Comment: Just curious, since I'm dealing with a similar problem. Did you ever find a solution?